# First Post, new to Apex. How can i get the DML statement out from the loop while creating new object and putting new values in the field?

Tags: apex

```java
public with sharing class CommodityCreatedByAccounts {

    @InvocableMethod public static void commodityCreation() {
        
        List<Account> checkAccount = [SELECT PersonalDataComplete__c,Name, Phone, E_Mail_Adresse__c FROM Account];

        for(Account i : checkAccount){
            if(i.PersonalDataComplete__c == true){    
                String csv = 'Phone, Email, Name\n';
                csv += i.Phone + ',' + i.E_Mail_Adresse__c + ',' + i.Name.escapeCsv() + '\n';
    
                String outputget= JSON.serialize(i);

                String fieldName1 = 'JsonData__c';
                String fieldName2 = 'CsvData__c';
                Commodity__c comm = new Commodity__c(PickStatus__c = 'Nicht zugeordnet', JsonData__c = 'old desc1', CsvData__c = 'old desc2');

                String jsonData = (String)comm.put(fieldName1, Outputget);
                String csvData = (String)comm.put(fieldName2, csv);   
                insert comm;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you create a new list of items that you want to create.

```
List<Commodity__c> insertCommodities = new List<Commodity__c>();
```

Then in the loop you create the individual commodities, and add them to that list:

```
for(Account i : checkAccount){
    ...
    // you can do this in one line but this is more readable.
    Commodity__c comm = new Commodity__c(PickStatus__c = 'Nicht zugeordnet', JsonData__c = 'old desc1', CsvData__c = 'old desc2');
    insertCommodities.add(comm);
}
```

Then, outside the for loop, insert all records in one DML Statement:

```
insert insertCommodities;
```

This will insert all the created records with less chance of hitting the governor limits.